# How to populate form html with json data from ws, using Typescript

Tags: html, angular, forms, typescript

I don't understand how to populate form when I get all data form ws.
I want to populate form from my function `productGetAll()`

my product.service

```
public productGetAll(): Observable<Product[]> {
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('x-access-token', this.auth.getCurrentUser().token);
return this.http.get(Api.getUrl(Api.URLS.productGetAll), {
  headers: headers
})
  .map((response: Response) => {
   let res = response.json();

    if (res.StatusCode === 1) {
      this.auth.logout();
    } else {
      return res.StatusDescription.map(prod => {
        return new Product(prod);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

This function `productGetAll(){}` I call in component `product.ts` like this code:

```
  public prod: Product[];
    this.ws.productGetAll().subscribe(
      prod=> {
        this.prod= prod;
      }
    );
```

This code is form that I want to populate

```
 this.productForm = this.fb.group({
      'active': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      'name': new FormControl('', Validators.required)
    });
```

My html code:

```
     <form [formGroup]="productForm ">
     <mat-slide-toggle formControlName="active" id="active" (change)="onChange($event)" [(ngModel)]="devicee[i]" (click)="onActiveHomeboxP(item.homeboxpackage_id)">
     </mat-slide-toggle>{{device}}
     <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12">                
 <input formControlName="name" id="name" type="text">
 </div>
  </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "populate form?" Do you mean you want to enter default values for the form or are you implying you want to dynamically create the form based off the data you receive?

Comment: @Narm I want to display in html my value that I get from productGetAll(){}

Comment: Ok, I still am not exactly sure how you want to display the data. However, from you code it looks like you set the data you get from your WS to this.prod which is a product[]. So if that is what you want to display you can simply use an *ngFor, like <div *ngFor="let item of prod">{{item}}</div>
Is this what you mean?